# How do I find the file responsible for triggering a reboot prompt?

Tags: windows-installer

I have a windows installer upgrade or patch which is prompting the user to reboot, but it shouldn't be necessary, and I need to determine where the reboot prompt is coming from.

I know this information is located in the msi install log, but it's not immediately obvious where it is located, and my log is long. What's the best way to find the place where the reboot is being triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboots are handled by the InstallValidate standard action.  You can get more information here:

[Logging of Reboot Requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369779%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the line which indicates the culprit. It looks like searching for `held` will be helpful.

```
Info 1603.The file C:\blah\blahblah.dll is being held in use.  Close that application and retry.
```